# Project References Not Linking when instantiating ProjectTemplates

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am trying to create a Visual Studio Project Template that contains a solution and two projects. The first project, ProjectA, has needs a reference to the second project, ProjectB. I found that I need to add the  tag to the ProjectTemplate.csproj for ProjectA. However, it adds the reference, but doesn't link it up. In other words it has the yellow flag on it like it would if the reference is missing. I am assuming that my path is correct, because with an intentionally incorrect path the reference doesn't show up at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated.